# I need a way to extract data from large dataset from nd2 files (up to 6 GB) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two large nd2 files (6GB volume) and i couldn't open em using python

```
import nd2



with nd2.ND2File('file.nd2') as myfile:

    print(myfile.metadata)
```

The code shuts down immediately when i run it

is there any way to make it work?
Rly need help